# How to fix Bluetooth DUN Phone Details Not detected?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, phone, modem-manager

I tried to connect Nokia 5233 to Ubuntu 14.04. I have Blueman installed and everything worked fine including file transfer. But when I try to connect DUN - over Bluetooth - I get an error message:

> Timed out while detecting phone details

Is there any solution? I want to access internet through this particular phone.

[modemmanager [image: Install modemmanager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/modemmanager) is already installed. With 12.04 the same phone worked fine and fast.